# Are discontinuous functions strictly non-differentiable

Tags: calculus

I encountered a function, where for all values of $x<0$, $(x^2)+(y^2)=2$, while for $x\ge 0$, $(x^2)+(y^2)=4$. My question is although the function is discontinuous at $x=0$, the slope $\frac{dy}{dx}$ at $x=0$ is still zero and also approaches zero for $0-$ and $0+$ situations. Should this function still be called non-differentiable on the basis of the conservative reason of discontinuity?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Compute the derivative more carefully - it has an exact definition in terms of a limit, and is not a heuristic thing. You'll see it doesn't exist:
$$\frac{dy}{dx}\bigg|_{0}\equiv \lim_{x\to 0}\frac{y(x)-y(0)}{x-0}$$
This limit does not exist, because it is approaching two values, depending on from which side $x$ is approaching zero. Do out the calculation carefully, and you'll see.

Comment: Ok I get it, right, I was using the bland differentiation formulas instead of going for the limiting definition. Right, thank you...:)

Comment: Glad I could help!

Answer (score 0):

When a function is discontinuous at a point, it is non-differentiable. For a function $f$ to be differentiable at a point, we must have $\lim\limits_{h\to 0}\frac{f(x+h) - f(x)}{h} = k$ for $k\in\mathbb{R}$. If $f$ is discontinuous at $x$, then we have a problem, because the numerator of this difference quotient will either not exist or will not be equal to zero. In either case, this limit will not exist so $f$ will not be differentiable.

However, you are correct that the left and right limits of the derivative may exist.

Comment: but if I define my function such that for x<a, f(x) is something and for x>a, f(x) is something else, I am defining the numerator for all points, as in the above case. Am I going wrong somewhere?

Comment: Compute the derivative carefully. Remember, the difference quotient needs to approach one value as $x\to 0$. In this case, it approaches two values, so there is no one value which we can call the derivative at 0.